# Simple redirect apache infinite loop

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'am using xampp under the windows 7. I've placed .htaccess in the %XAMPP_ROOT%/htdocs. .htaccess contained the folowing line:

```
Redirect / http://localhost/test.php/
```

After the typing `http://localhost` into the browser's address field I've an infinte loop error to a 
`http://localhost/test.php/test.php/test.php/test.php/test.php/test.php/test.php/test.php/test.php/test.php/test.php/test.php/test.php/test.php/test.php/test.php/test.php/test.php/test.php/test.php/`. But I'm expected that I'm redirected to `http://localhost/test.php/`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `RedirectMatch` for avoiding this scenario using regex:

```
RedirectMatch ^/?$ http://localhost/test.php/
```

Answer (score 3):

A [Redirect directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) matches everything beginning with the provided URL:

> Then any request beginning with URL-Path will return a redirect request to the client at the location of the target URL.

That means that `/` will match every request including `/test.php/`. Furthermore, everything after the slash will be appended to the target URL. That is why you get the recursive URL.

You have to use [RedirectMatch](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch) to match only the root path `/`.

```
RedirectMatch ^/?$ http://localhost/test.php/
```

Thanks [anubhava](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21824947/5593430) for that solution.